# Calculate the sum $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{4n-3}{n^3-4n}$

Tags: calculus, summation, power-series

$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{4n-3}{n^3-4n}$$
I think it is related to power series, because it is the topic, but I have no idea how to get there.
Could you give a hint?

Comment: Are you just trying to prove convergence or actually calculate the value of the infinite sum?

Comment: @spencer calculate

Comment: There is a method for calculating such sums in terms of a finite sum of polygamma functions. Would that be of interest to you?

Comment: I'll check that. But there has to be "easier" method.

Comment: @Mihail: partial fractions $\frac{A}{n}+\frac{B}{n-2}+\frac{C}{n+2}$ and then it might telescope..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By partial fractions
$$\begin{align}\sum\limits_{n=3}^\infty\frac{4n-3}{n^3-4n}&=\sum\limits_{n=3}^\infty\frac{5}{8(n-2)}+\frac{3}{4n}-\frac{11}{8(n+2)}
\\&=\sum\limits_{n=1}^4\frac{5}{8n}+\sum\limits_{n=3}^4\frac{3}{4n}+\sum\limits_{n=5}^\infty\frac{5}{8n}+\frac{3}{4n}-\frac{11}{8n}
\\&=\sum\limits_{n=1}^4\frac{5}{8n}+\sum\limits_{n=3}^4\frac{3}{4n}
\\&=\frac{167}{96}
\end{align}$$

Comment: don't all the series diverge?

Comment: @abel good point. Will fix.

Comment: @abel Yeah, I misinterpreted your comment. You are right

Comment: @abel should be good now. I didn't need that line anyway

Comment: peter, nice work(+1).

Answer (score 2):

[This link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%284n-3%29%2F%28n%5E3-4n%29) shows you the partial fraction decomposition.

If you carefully look at the terms cancelling out, you should be able 
to calculate the sum.

Answer (score 1):

see if this helps.

$$\frac{a}{(n-2)n} - \frac{b}{n(n+2)}  = \frac{(a-b)n+2(a+b)}{(n-2)n(n+2)}$$  choose $a, b$ so that $$ a- b = 4, 2a + 2b = -3 \to a = \frac54, b = -\frac{11}4$$

Answer (score 1):

You can write your sum as the sum of four telescoping sums by noting that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{4n-3}{n^{3}-4n} &=&\frac{3/4}{n}+\frac{5/8}{\left( n-2\right) }-\frac{%
11/8}{\left( n+2\right) } \\
&=&\left( \frac{5/8}{n-2}-\frac{5/8}{n-1}\right) +\left( \frac{5/8}{n-1}-%
\frac{5/8}{n}\right) +\left( \frac{11/8}{n}-\frac{11/8}{n+1}\right) +\left( 
\frac{11/8}{n+1}-\frac{11/8}{n+2}\right) 
\end{eqnarray*}
can you take it from here?